# Browse from Internet to asp.net web app on Windows server IIS on new AWS EC2 VM gets WINDOWS 2016 SERVER "error 403 Access is denied"

Tags: windows, iis, web-server, asp.net

THE PROBLEM:
When I browse from external Internet or on the server itself my ASP.NET web app hosted on Windows Server 2016 IIS on my new AWS EC2 VM, I get  "error 403 Access is denied".

ATTEMPTS TO FIX...
IIS > Connections > my_web_site > browse doesn't work: "The webpage cannot be found"
IIS > Connections > my_web_site > Manage Website > browse cmd gets Server Error

IIS > Connections > my_web_site > Edit Bindings > browse gets Server Error

BACKGROUND...
ASP.NET works ok on previous Azure VM.

ASP.NET app runs ok when I debug it from Visual Studio on VM.

All IIS bindings set up just like on previous Azure VM.

WEB APP'S IIS PROPERTIES...……….
[image]

Comment: Read IIS log files to learn what sub status you hit https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you did not put the code in folder `C:\inetpub\wwwroot`.
In case code is located in a folder different from this, you should give full control permission to the folder for user IIS_USRS.  This is the user which IIS uses to service the content.

Comment: Code is located at a different path and folder than this, where it has been for about 10 years.  Web app has been running on Windows server 2012 R2 for the last few years on Azure.  Now I'm moving it to AWS.

Comment: Does web app need to be in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ for Windows Server 2016?  it is presently in C:\PRIMARY\etcetct\ which worked OK for years on Windows Server 2012 R2.

Comment: Does the folder has sufficient permissions for IIS_USR to read/write and execute the content inside code folder.

Comment: I set web site's folder C:\PRIMARY\etcetc\ to full control by everyone and it still doesn't work.